# Problem with Kotlin readLine() function using IntelliJ internal console

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea

When I try to read some value from a user, I get strange behavior.

For example, if I have one simple program:

```
fun main() {
    print("insert value: ")
    val tmp = readLine()
    println("value = $tmp")
}
```

I would expect the next behavior of the program:

```
insert value: 1
value = 1
```

But I get the next behavior:

```
insert value: 1
1
value = 1
```

So I would expect to insert the value `1`, hit `Enter`, and the program would output `value = 1`. But instead of this, I have to input the value `1`, hit `Enter`, input the value `1`, hit `Enter`, and then I get the desired output.

Is there any option to run the Kotlin program in an external console instead of the IntelliJ internal console? Because I updated IntelliJ to the latest version and assume that maybe there is a problem with the new version?

Comment: I can't reproduce this, it's working fine for me in version 2020.2.4

Comment: Thanks for your response. I got an idea that maybe Avast can have some issues with the console. But I tried to turn it off but without luck.

Comment: Happening for me on 2020.3. It seems it does not matter what you enter before the first `Enter`, it is accepting the second input line only.

Comment: After updating Kotlin plugin to 203-1.4.21-release-IJ5981.133 it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

on your `Kotlin REPL`

```
   fun main() {
        print("insert value: ")
        val tmp = readLine()
        println("value = $tmp")
    }
    main()
```

Then to execute you press `Ctrl`+`Enter`

You get:

```
insert value:
```

then insert the value 1 and press `Ctrl`+`Enter` one more time to execute.

and the output is:

```
insert value: 1
value = 1
```